# How to change items order in translated main-menu?

Tags: drupal

I have a problem with determining the position of main-menu items after their translation. I can only determine the positions of elements in the original language (polish) when doing a translation, I can not determine the position of the elements in the main-menu in the new language. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different menu for each language.
Show the menu blocks only on the used language.
It's some more work but this way you have total control over each menu.